# Unable to start Sphinx searchd daemon due to already running searchd process, and it restarts just after killing it

Tags: sphinx, daemon, ubuntu-11.10

When I try to start searchd, it gives the following error.

bind() failed on 0.0.0.0, retrying...

FATAL: bind() failed on 0.0.0.0: Illegal seek

---

I can find a searchd process running

root     14863  0.1  0.0  73884  3960 ?        Ssl  23:21   0:00 /usr/bin/searchd --nodetach

Now, when i kill it or try to stop it (searchd --stop), it instantly restarts.

root     15841  0.5  0.0  73884  3960 ?        Ssl  23:33   0:00 /usr/bin/searchd --nodetach

---

I am guessing there is some setting by which it automatically starts when the process is not running. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: dmesg | tail gives this.

***
[ 1733.055257] init: sphinxsearch main process (5743) killed by KILL signal
[ 1733.055325] init: sphinxsearch main process ended, respawning

***   

There must be some setting for this.

Answer (score 7):

By default, it seems like the debian package will start Sphinx with an additional keepalive process. I was able to stop it successfully with this;

> sudo service sphinxsearch stop

Answer (score 1):

the 'init: ... main process ended, respawning' suggests there is something in the init script that sets a watchdog to make sure sphinx doesnt die.

Perhaps you need to shutdown sphinx via the init script itself

```
/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch stop
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, Upstart is responsible for respawning searchd after you attempt to stop/kill it.

Since we know that this process is being managed by upstart, we can terminate the daemon using "stop sphinxsearch" and then start it again with "start sphinxsearch".

If you want to kill it normally like any other process, then you can remove the "--nodetach" argument in the config file /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf. However, by doing this, you can no longer stop the process using "stop sphinxsearch".

Answer (score -1):

No, there are no any sphinx option to restart Sphinx.
Probably some monitoring tool like monit installed for Sphinx.